# HF Connector - Replace parts in a Nexus S

Tags: hardware, samsung-nexus-s

I have a Nexus S device (model i9023).

My current earpiece is torn - the wires are cut, and the body could not be screwed out because the specific body's screw is stuck. However, I can gently replace it without breaking the body.

I see a "HF" connector connected to the left of what I see in the picture of the earpiece unit.

To be more specific, I took some pictures of it, since I can't get the data from 
[fixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus+S+Teardown/4365/2).

Here's a picture of what dealers are selling in eBay. This picture is pretty descriptive.

All dealers provide a unit containing the earpieace speaker as seen upwards,
a proximity sensor as seen below and the connector to the motherboard, to the right.

[image: earpiece]

This is what I saw in fixit:

[image: fixit]

as you can see upwards, there's another group of wires (orange) to the right of the proximity sensor, which doesn't exist in the seller's unit.

The pictures I took of my device shows exactly what I mean:

This **"HF" wires** down there doesn't exist in the units for sale

[image: part1]
[image: part2]

> Don't mind the fact that in my pictures there's no speaker, its
>   because its been torn. that's the reason why I was wandering around thinking of buying a new EM-Tech EME1511AFRC replacement unit in the first place...

So does anyone know what's that HF and what am I losing if I buy a new unit without it?

Answer (score 0):

At first note that the i9023 is the Nexus S (with S-LCD) and not a Nexus One.

Here's [iFixit's teardown](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Nexus+S+Teardown/4365/2).

Here's what iFixit says: *The EM-Tech EME1511AFRC integrates the earpiece speaker, loudspeaker for speakerphone and media use, and a sensor bank all into one unit with a singular shared data connector.*

That sensor bank includes at least the proximity sensor, a light sensor (for LCD dimming) and maybe some of the rest of the sensors (accelerometer, gyro, compass).

Comment: First of all, a HUGE thank you, ce4.

This link is extremely helpful although it didn't answer my question yet.

I'm now updating the question with further input.

Comment: I would solder it back together if feasible. If that is not an option, search foe a replacement part on ebay, maybe? Or buy a whole (broken ) replacement Nexus S (e.g.with a shattered display)

Comment: How do you solder back that torn wired package? 
I'm talking about the orange wires that are torn. 

Is it possible?

Comment: after disconnecting the unit's connector, I've had no phone sound, so the HF connector connects to the black plastic unit which is the phone's speaker.

What I'll have to do is to solder the wires to the earpiece somehow.

Comment: Good question, the unit is broken anyway? You definitely need a steady hand, experience in soldering and dissecting electronics. On the plus side: It's only 2 wires and you have solder points on the connector end and probably some solder points in the loudspeaker too. Not easy to tell remotely. If you find a cheap donator for spare parts (i.e., a differently broken Nexus S) on ebay, that'll also work.

Comment: my earpiece unit like I stated and also shown in the pictures is broken, since the earpiece speaker is torn from it (wires were cut)

And I'll definitely need to solder the new unit to the  speakerphone's wires professionally.

Yes, it seems that soldering was done from factory, as you can see in the photo I took, above the  + - marks.

Comment: Now I got it (another pic on [ifixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing+Nexus+S+Speaker/8804/3)). If there are no directly available solder junctions for the earpiece, it'll maybe be hard to fix it (I have done that a few times using thin unwound wire from an inductance coil). Maybe buying an otherwise broken donator Nexus S from ebay is the quicker path.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your idea correctly:
If you're talking about trying to solder back the wired orange ribbons together so that the earpiece will be attached to the unit again, then I think its too tiny and I prefer to just buy another earpiece+proximity_sensor integrated unit, which is available for sale for just 5$ in eBay, and solder it with the existing speakerphone's + - terminals.

Comment: Ah, sure. That's of course a good idea, if it's only 5$ (I'm in germany actually, where supply is a little sparser).

Answer (score 0):

The black plastic, the one that's connected with those HF wires is the phone speaker,
IHF Speaker.

The unit I showed is the earpiece speaker and a proximity sensor, an integrated circuit.

The thing is that the **integrated circuit is the one with the data connector** to the motherboard
and the phone-speaker's wires are soldered with two wires of the integrated circuit to receive data.

My earpiece wires were cut.

So if I replace only the integrated circuit, I can solder the right wires, like they did originally, onto my existing speaker's wires.

Problem could be solved by soldering.